# Firestore giving same data with startAfter

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My query

```
         Firebase.firestore.document(userId!!)
                .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGE_GROUPS)
                .document(messageGroupId!!)
                .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
                .orderBy("createdTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(Constants.PAGE_SIZE.toLong())
                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                   if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                     }
                 if (querySnapshot?.documents.isNotNullOrEmpty() && lastVisible == null) {
                         lastVisible = querySnapshot?.documents?.get(querySnapshot.documents.size-1)
                   }
               }
```

For second page I am using

```
      Firebase.firestore.document(userId!!)
        .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGE_GROUPS)
        .document(messageGroupId!!)
        .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
        .orderBy("createdTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .startAfter(lastVisible)
        .limit(Constants.PAGE_SIZE.toLong())
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->

        if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        if (querySnapshot?.documents.isNotNullOrEmpty() ) {
               lastVisible = querySnapshot?.documents?.get(querySnapshot.documents.size - 1)
        }

    }
```

Even after adding `.startAfter(lastVisible)` in second query the result is the same . My page size is 25 and I get same 25 elements with first and second query . Here `createdTime` is a `Timestamp` . The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) says that this will give next 25 elements . So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you log the `createdTime` and document ID of `lastVisible` right before the second query, what does it show in the output? It would also help if you logged something inside the callbacks to show what documents were retrieved, so that we are all looking at the same output.

Comment: It shows the 25th element , last visible is fine . I managed to fix it by passing created time `.startAfter(lastVisibleMessage?.createdTime)` instead of `DocumentSnapshot`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by passing `.startAfter(lastVisibleMessage?.createdTime)` instead of `DocumentSnapshot`

Here are the changes I made

```
Firebase.firestore.document(userId!!)
                .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGE_GROUPS)
                .document(messageGroupId!!)
                .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
                .orderBy("createdTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(Constants.PAGE_SIZE.toLong())
                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                   if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                     }
                 //parsing querySnapshot to my list of objects
                val messagesListTmp = getMessagesFromDocumentSnapshot(querySnapshot)
                 if (querySnapshot?.documents.isNotNullOrEmpty() && lastVisibleMessage == null) {
                        lastVisibleMessage = messagesListTmp.last()
                   }
               }
```

Second Query:-

```
  Firebase.firestore.document(userId!!)
    .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGE_GROUPS)
    .document(messageGroupId!!)
    .collection(Constants.FIREBASE_DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
    .orderBy("createdTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .startAfter(lastVisibleMessage?.createdTime)
    .limit(Constants.PAGE_SIZE.toLong())
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->

    if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
        return@addSnapshotListener
    } 
        //parsing querySnapshot to my list of objects
      val messagesListTmp = getMessagesFromDocumentSnapshot(querySnapshot)
        if (querySnapshot?.documents.isNotNullOrEmpty()) {
               lastVisibleMessage = messagesListTmp.last()
          }

}
```